# Inserting date from Php

Tags: php, date, content-management-system

I have in my CMS a text field,where I can add a last's game result and post it in the database. The only thing I am missing,and need help is how to add the date for this. For example the last game of Manchester United was on Tue,12th of Junuary. I want to put that date in my CMS and the database. How should I do it? Here is my code.

```
<body>
<form action="index.php?insert_last_game" method="post"> 
    <table width="795" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr bgcolor="#FF6600">
            <td colspan="6" align="center"><h1>Insert Last Game:</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF6600"><strong>Game:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="game" size="60"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF6600"><strong>Game:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="date" size="60"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FF6600">
            <td colspan="6" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**and my php part.**

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$post_game = $_POST['game'];
$post_date = date('d-m-y');
if($post_game==''){
echo "<script>alert('Please fill in all fields')</script>";
exit();
}
else {
$insert_game = "insert into last_game (game,date) values ('$post_game','$post_date')";
$run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$insert_game); 
echo "<script>alert('Post Has been Published!')</script>";
echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_last_game','_self')</script>";
}
}
?>
```

The above gives me the date of the added game. I want to put the date from a textfield as shown. 
[image: My CMS]
  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your HTML, you named the second label Game, instead of date.

```
<td align="right" bgcolor="#FF6600"><strong>Game:</strong></td>
```

To do what you desire, you must do this in your PHP

```
$post_game = $_POST['game'];
$time = strtotime($_POST['date']);
$post_date = date('d-m-y',$time);
```

You already did the rest.

If you wish to format the date as `Tue, 12th of Junuary` you can do this:

```
$post_date = date('D, jS', $time) . ' of ' . date('F', $time);
```

Also congratulations on using `mysqli_`

Comment: Thank you sir. It is working. :). What if I want to store the date as ie 12,Jun 2016?. I should the date('d-m-y') to something else right?

Comment: Yeah date('d-m-y') is the format you're using. You can see all formats in here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

add with strtotime, see http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php

show with date, example:

```
$test = strtotime("now");
echo date("jS F, Y", $test);
```